# w3c dom and the javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I was seeing the W3C Document Object Model and excited that different programming languages have to implement their interfaces accordingly. Like other languages, JavaScript also maintains the DOM.

So I'm curious to know about the following questions:

1. Which versions of javascript implements dom level 1, 2,3 and so
   forth.
2. Are they all implemented in javascript?
3. Are they implemented by javascript or implemented by ECMAScript and
   followed by JavaScript?
4. And what are the IDL definitions described in W3C DOM: Are they
   needed to understand for javascript developers or is that the symbol
   of implementation by HTML?

Comment: One question per question please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The pedantic answer is "none".
   There is no formal mapping of JS iteration to DOM-specification.
   In general, JS-versioning has all but been abandoned (save major overhauls), though can be seen as signposts of when you might *start* to consider feature-checking.
   This is because...
2. Not really, no.
   That is to say, yes, the APIs which you will use to interface with the HTML DOM are all implemented in JavaScript...
   However, no browser has a stable, feature-complete implementation of either
   JS ***or*** HTML DOM[1-4].
   Because both specs are so large, and ever-changing, different vendors have prioritized different features at different times, leading to patches of incompatibility.
   To further this actual answer, the JS spec says nothing of DOM or BOM ("Browser ...") APIs.
   This is the reason #1 must be a *"No"*, as different DOM/BOM combinations on different JS implementations leads to the fundamental inability to say "All JS1.7-compliant browsers are DOM3 compliant."
   The truth is that no browser is wholly compliant with either spec, and neither spec is the latest, anyway.  As for technical-implementation (the code ***behind*** the API), there are no rules, so long as the behaviour is well-defined.  Some browsers defer to C/C++ for core JS/DOM/BOM functionality, while older IE browsers had an ActiveX layer between the browser and JS DOM access (making touching elements for any reason arbitrarily expensive).
3. Here's the rub.
   Most people would consider them to be different things.
   Most people would think "JS is the thing that you use in the browser, to do your scripting.".
   Really, ECMAScript and JavaScript are the same thing, and "JavaScript" is a Sun (now Oracle) trademark...  how none of us are getting sued is a mystery.
   JS/ECMAS knows nothing of DOM or BOM, and it's up to the vendors to include DOM-access in their browser (on a per-feature, rather than per-version basis).  It should also be noted that while VendorA might implement a feature from the spec, and VendorB might omit it, VendorC might have an off-standard implementation of it, and also implement a similar but completely out-of-spec feature, as well.
4. Don't worry about the DOM implementation specifics.
   As a JS-dev, you won't need to know or care what a Java implementation of an HTML node might look like.
   Even with WebIDL, and moving away from the old-world Java-centric view, as far as day-to-day usage of JS as a language, the DOM-node interfaces are as dry as toast, unbuttered, face-down in a sand dune, unless it's really what you're into.
   Even then, it's more for people who make the browsers, and not the people who make things which run in them.

These aren't all of the answers.  And while I've tried to remain subjective, I'm sure there's a little objectivism in there, as they aren't wholly cut and dry.  I've tried to be, at least, factual.

From an engineering perspective, being careful about how and when you use the DOM in client-side JS is important -- both for making code portable and for allowing each language in the client-side stack to have access to the HTML in question, without doing somersaults in JS, to accommodate, because you built your whole site using DOM construction in JS.

From a pragmatic standpoint, rather than trying to match features to versions, use sites like http://caniuse.com to match features to browser versions. It's much more productive.

And have fun.

Comment: This is a very nice answer like as other answers from you. And continue to help SO thanks.

Comment: It's *possible*, but shouldn't exist.  What I'm saying is this:  IE9 is still missing support for features that other browsers put in around JS1.7.  This is why JS versions are useless.  You need to check if a browser supports a feature/function/syntax that you want to use... ...not whether it's JS1.6, JS1.7, JS1.85... those numbers don't actually tell you anything useful.  FireFox has had some features from ES6 since their JS1.7 browser...  ...but was missing support for other 1.7 features, at the same time...

Comment: @C-link So it's 100% possible for a browser to support the "new" `localStorage` feature of modern web browsers, but still not have any support for `addEventListener`, which is the most fundamental part of interacting with the user, through their use of the page (that particular browser is IE8).  So the key is to not try to think in versions, but to think "do I have a `localStorage` I can use?", "do I have an `el.addEventListener()` I can use?". Test for each ***part*** of DOM/JS you want to use, rather than assuming that JS version X.0 will support 100% of DOM version Y. It won't, ever.